# Using a specific (git) branch in a mercurial subrepository

Tags: git, mercurial, branch, subrepos, mercurial-subrepos

I have a mercurial project in which I would like to use jQuery-File-Upload.
I added the following to my `.hgsub` file in order to create a subrepo for this plugin:

```
public/assets/common/js/filedrop = [git]git://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.git
```

The problem I have is that I need to use in the `jquery-ui` branch of this git repo in my project.

Is there any way to specify the branch name of a git repo to pull as a hg subrepo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it out by myself.

In fact you don't need to do anything special. All you have to do, after editing your `.hgsub` to add your subrepo, and cloning it, is to change directory to that repository, checkout the desired branch or rev and commit using mercurial.

In my case, the whole process was (in a terminal):

```
$ echo "public/assets/common/js/jQuery-File-Upload = [git]git://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.git" >> .hgsub
$ cd public/assets/common/js/
$ git clone git://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.git
$ cd jQuery-File-Upload
$ git checkout jquery-ui
$ hg commit -m"ADDED: jQuery-File-Upload subrepo (jquery branch)"
```